# First key in OrderedDict that exceeds threshold

Tags: python, key, threshold, ordereddictionary

Say I have an `OrderedDict`:

```
a = OrderedDict([(5, 'a'), (7, 'b'), (10, 'c')])
```

Is there an efficient way to get the first value whose key exceeds a certain threshold, *without* looping over all keys?

Examples:

```
>>> get_first(a, 6)
'a'
>>> get_first(a, 3)
None
>>> get_first(a, 8)
'b'
```

I would like to avoid having to implement binary search myself. Is there an efficient out-of-the-box implementation available?

Comment: First hit for *"Python binary search"*: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html). Come on.

Comment: Note that "ordered" does not imply "sorted".

Comment: If the keys are not in sorted order, so far as I can see there cannot exist an algorithm that is materially faster than looping over the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement a binary search yourself, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for that. However, OrderedDict is not sorted so you can't use a binary search on the dictionary keys unless you sort them first, and that won't be very efficient (in fact it's likely to be faster to just loop over the keys).

If you maintain a sorted list of keys, then that could work, or if you use an implementation of a dictionary that is sorted. You can use the built-in `collections.OrderedDict` but then you would have to maintain the sorting yourself, or you can use some btree implementation, I think there are several.

I have only used [BTree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BTrees), it's written in C and very fast, but the API is somewhat obtuse.